# Здраствуйте, подскажите как сделать так, чтоби можно било вводить только 0 или 1, а при вводе любого другого числа видавало" Error"?

Tags: java

Буду благодарен.Зарание спасибо большое

Comment: Спасибо Андрей, очень помог. А еще вопрос: если скажем нужно ввести не х, а n елементов массива с таким же ограничением?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Scaner vvod = new Scaner(System.in);
    int x = vvod.nextInt();
    if(x!=0 || x!=1){
        //sout("Eror");
        throw Exceptionl;
    }
    Или можно воспользоваться assert(x!=0 || x!=1)

Для массива:
int n = ...;
int[] mass = new mass[n];
for(int i = 0; i < mass.length(); i++){
       Scaner vvod = new Scaner(System.in);
       int x = vvod.nextInt();
       if(x!=0 || x!=1){
        //sout("Eror");
        throw Exceptionl;
    }
       else{
          mass[i] = x;
     }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Андрей, очень помог. А еще вопрос: если скажем нужно ввести не х, а n елементов массива с таким же ограничением?

Comment: Рад что помог, ещё больше буду рад если лайк поставишь и как ответ отметишь)))

Comment: Thanks, работает, но  throw Exceptionl; не работал(красным виделялся) и я использовал break/